# Can I connect more than one external monitor with only one thunderbolt port?

Tags: imac, display, thunderbolt

Mid-2011 iMac 21.5 inch
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600S CPU @ 2.80GHz
RAM: 8.00 GB

Right now, I connect an external monitor to my iMac using the one thunderbolt port that I have. Is it possible to connect a second external monitor? If so, how?

Comment: You need to be sure you don't confuse Thunderbolt with Mini Display Port...

If you are using a thunderbolt display then yes you can daisy chain into the back of the other monitor.

However in all likelihood you are using a normal HDMI/DVI/VGA monitor with a Mini Display Port adapter, this is not daisy chain-able with any kind of adapters.

You can however get USB, and Thunderbolt accessories that create virtual monitors, these can likely do what you want but I am not sure if the video from them is accelerated by the graphics card or done in software. Nor how many you can have.

Answer (score 1):

thunderbolt dock will do it.  get one that adds dvi, hdmi or passthrough thunderbolt.

my caldigit does hdmi + passthrough thunderbolt so i can get 2 displays on there.

Answer (score -1):

Although I am not using multiple monitors on my new Macbook Pro 15" (2015), I purchased CalDigit's ThunderStation 2 model. That product connected to your iMac will provide support for thunderbolt / mini displayport passthrough as well as an HDMI port.  So, you should be able to connect 2 external monitors to your iMac via this device. => http://www.caldigit.com/thunderbolt-2-dock-TS2/index.asp

Comment: Hi Jerry, this information may be better included as additional sourcing/product referral to the existing answer left by venicejeff, which already recommends the product as a valid answer. Thank you, though, for the followup and research!

Comment: OK.  Not a problem. Cheers..